# How to see array objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

This line:

```
alert("<b>feeds.entries["+j+"] is </b>=>"+feeds.entries[j]+"<br>");
```

gives this result:

```
<b>feeds.entries[0] is </b>=>[object Object]<br>
```

I would like to print the list of objects so that I can use them.

This array is being called as such:

```
var entry=feeds.entries[i];
```

and entry.title, prints the title of the image.  I guessed at "title", and would like to see all the other objects feeds.entries[] contains, but my alert above, prints "[object Object]".  The script is zRSSFeed which is an RSS parser.  I'm trying to parse a Menalto Gallery 2 (or g2) RSS feed.

Comment: Post the code where you construct the feeds and entries objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function join(obj) {
    var ret = '';
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        ret += i + ': ' + obj[i]
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
alert("<b>feeds.entries["+j+"] is </b>=>"+join(feeds.entries[j])+"<br>");
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/x47zy/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't render string and object together as they are different type. do print object separately `alert(feeds.entries[j])`. 
I think it is good to use `console.log` instead of `alert` for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you download and install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), then read the section on [Firebug and logging](http://getfirebug.com/logging).  It will show you how to log to the console.

I'm also a fan of the [YUI 2 Logger](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/logger/) which displays the messages in a floating window.  Either way, using `alert` is a sure way to slow down development and drive yourself insane.  Development should be more fun than that.

As an aside, take a look at the [`YAHOO.lang.dump()`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.lang.html) method which shows what is inside an object. `[Object object]` isn't very useful as you've discovered.

Answer (score 1):

if you mean to use them in the browser console, use

```
for (var i==0; i<feeds.entries.length; i++){
   console.log(feeds.entries[i]);
}
```

otherwise, please explain more clearly what you want, and how you want to represent your
objects or their attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Try outputting it as JSON:

```
alert("<b>feeds.entries["+j+"] is </b>=>"+JSON.stringify(feeds.entries[j])+"<br>");
```

I don't see why you have the tags in the `alert` though, as they do nothing.

```
alert("feeds.entries["+j+"] is =>" + JSON.stringify(feeds.entries[j]));
```

However, if you are using Chrome, I suggest you simply `console.log` the object(s) and open up the developer console to view the object.

Comment: I don't know how to find, activate, use, etc. the "console log"

Comment: If you're on Mac, `Cmd+Alt+j`. Windows is probably `Ctrl-Alt-j`. Otherwise, just go to View -> Developer -> Javascript console.